# Ordering observations in HIVE

Tags: hive

In HIVE, we have order by, distribute by, sort by, cluster by to arrange records.

**Order by:** Here, the o/p all the mappers are passed to only a single reducer and the reducer does the ordering. When we print the final dataset, we see that it is sorted by given columns.

**Distribute by:** After mappers are run, the resultant is hashed by the given columns and passed into different reducers.

**Sort by:** It sorts observations within a Single reducer. So to achieve ordering, we have to call distribute by and then sort by.

**Cluster by:** It wraps distribute by and sort by together.

When we print the query resultant by using any of the above methods (order by/ distribute by & sort by / cluster by), I see that the whole dataset is sorted by the given columns.
So I understand that when we print the results in console, even in case of distribute by&sort by OR cluster by, the output files of all reducers are read and passed into single reducer and
sorted; then output is printed.

Only when we save the query output, order by saves it in a single output where as the other two save the result in multiple files (depends on the number of reducers ran).

Is my understanding correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide PLAN + execution logs confirming that it was distributed between many reducers then it was really last single reducer ordering in case of distribute+sort?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question. I actually practice in my laptop where I don't have  large tables. I am reading into many logs/portal and would like to confirm my understanding about all the terms. Thanks!